# How to query on a result of another query?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to perform a query on a result of another query in `Oracle Database`. In this case, I want to get all the customers information from customer table `customer(customer_name(PK), customer_street, customer_city)` ,
Who are included after the following query:

```sql
SELECT customer_name
FROM depositor
UNION
SELECT customer_name
FROM borrower
```

All the tables:

1. Branch (branch_name, branch_city, assets)
2. Customer (customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)
3. Account (account_number, branch_name, balance)
4. Loan (loan_number, branch_name, amount)
5. Depositor (customer_name, account_number)
6. Borrower (customer_name, loan_number)

Comment: Do you have a kind of "*customer_details*" table, or your customer information are stored only in the two tables "*depositor*" and "*borrower*"?

Comment: Please see the question again. I have just added all the tables.

Comment: Interesting. Can you also show the matching references between the tables?

Comment: `customer_name`

Comment: MT0's answer should get what you need. If you want to show further information too, it's sufficient to join "*customer*" with your other tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customer c
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   depositor d
               WHERE  c.customer_name = d.customer_name)
OR     EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   borrower b
               WHERE  c.customer_name = b.customer_name)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customer c
WHERE  EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM   depositor d
          WHERE  c.customer_name = d.customer_name
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 1
          FROM   borrower b
          WHERE  c.customer_name = b.customer_name
       )
```

or `IN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customer
WHERE  customer_name IN ( SELECT customer_name FROM depositor )
OR     customer_name IN ( SELECT customer_name FROM borrower )
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customer
WHERE  customer_name IN (
         SELECT customer_name FROM depositor
       UNION ALL
         SELECT customer_name FROM borrower
       )
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` and just `UNION` are same?

Comment: @PrimerCielo `UNION ALL` returns all the rows, `UNION` does extra work to filter out duplicates. You do not need to do that extra work and can just use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: When there are no duplicates in the data, do you know whether using one over the other would make any difference in terms of performance? @MT0

Comment: @lemon The database does not know there are no duplicates. `UNION ALL` is more performant than `UNION`.